# Dual boot Yoga 2

Tags: windows, android, tablet

Am looking at a new tablet for work. I do development for both the .net framework and android devices. I'm aware the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro can run Android or Windows but can any tell me if it can run both as a dual boot configuration? Not been able to find much useful information among all the marketing blurb on the lenovo website.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about latest technology. Recently, Asus introduced a Transformer Book V, a hybrid that could switch between operating systems with just the press of a button. And this was done after they had taken down the previous version. So I am assuming that this version could offer something good.

Obviously, we have to wait a while and see when it's available in the market.